# Neovim lsp configuration

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, lsp

I'm a beginner in Vim/Neovim world.

I understand that LSP is for autocompletion, auto import, signature info, etc...

So I have installed [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim).

But I have some question about the concept :

- if I have coc.nvim is usefull to setup the builtin LSP with [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig) ?
- if I add another LSP like [coq_nvim](https://github.com/ms-jpq/coq_nvim) or [lspsaga](https://github.com/glepnir/lspsaga.nvim)

Is it a good or a bad idea?

Will it create conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

Both plugins have the same scope. They will contact the same LSP server and try to use the result in a similar way.

I believe it will only create conflict.

Comment: To be honest, this does not answer the question and a bit redundant.

Comment: Is the question till open? How can we help you?